# Add custom taxonomy metadata field to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a custom metadata field to my custom taxonomy term for a custom post type in WordPress. Basically, I want to add a Subtitle field to my Categories for my Post type.

I was able to add the custom field to my edit form by hooking into the edit_tag_form_fields` action.

```
function custom_edit_tag_form_fields( $tag ) {
    $meta_type = 'myCustomPostType_myCustomTaxonomy';
    $object_id = $tag->term_id;
    $meta_key = 'subtitle';
    $single = true;
    $value = get_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $single);
?>
<tr class="form-field term-description-wrap">
    <th scope="row">
        <label for="subtitle">Subtitle</label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input name="subtitle" id="subtitle" type="text" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" size="40" />
    </td>
</tr>   
<?php
}
```

In order to save the metadata, I added a hook to the `edited_terms` action for collecting and saving the inputted data.

```
function custom_edited_terms( $term_id ) {
    $meta_type = 'myCustomPostType_myCustomTaxonomy';
    $object_id = $term_id;  
    $meta_key = 'subtitle';
    $prev_value = null;

    if( isset($_POST[$meta_key]) ) {
        $meta_value = esc_attr( $_POST[$meta_key] );
        update_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value);
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why it isn't being stored into the database. If I echo `$value`, I get an empty string. I would expect it to be the value that I type into the input field.

Comment: Here, you have updated value using update_metadata() which uses the _get_meta_table() to retrieve the table name to store the value.
If _get_meta_table() doesn't found table then it returns false and there is no meta table for your custom meta type.
You can refer : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_get_meta_table/#source-code
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L0

Comment: @WisdmLabs thanks for the additional information. I will take a look into those items. I realize I'm using a core function that isn't designed for use in themes and such, but I'm just trying to build a custom application as a learning resource. I think you may be right about the tables.

Comment: Thanks @WisdmLabs. I was able to figure out my problem with your direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure out the problem I was having, thanks to [@WisdmLabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993125/wisdmlabs) for pointing me in the right direction.

Even though my custom post type had custom taxonomy, it was still using the original WordPress tables for `posts` and `terms`. My problem was that I was incorrectly using a custom name for `$meta_type`. The $meta_type variable is directly related to the table name that is used in `update_metadata`.  This is why it wasn't saving in the database. It was trying to save it to a table called `'myCustomPostType_myCustomTaxonomy' . 'meta'`.

For the default taxonomy, WordPress is using the `termmeta` table, so I just had to change the following lines in both functions from this:

```
$meta_type = 'myCustomPostType_myCustomTaxonomy';
```

To this:

```
global $wpdb;
$meta_type = substr($wpdb->termmeta, strlen($wpdb->prefix), strlen('meta')); // equates to 'term'
```

Instead of just hardcoding `$meta_type = 'term';`, I decided to take the actual `wp_prefex_termmeta` table that is used in the global `$wpdb` database object and work back from there to future-proof it in case the WP changes the word that is used for taxonomy tables.

Unfortunately, the `meta` suffix in WordPress is hardcoded in the version I'm using, WordPress 4.4. Doubt that will ever change anytime soon, though.

Answer (score 4):

have you read about the **term meta data** introduced with Wordpress 4.4 ?

```
function taxonomy_client_extra_field_url_display( $client ) {

    $client_url = get_term_meta( $client->term_id, 'client-url', true );

    ?>
    <tr class="form-field term-description-wrap">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="client_url"><?php _e( 'Client URL', 'wp-job-manager' );?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input name="term_meta[client-url]" id="client_url" type="text" value="<?php echo $client_url; ?>" size="40" />
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <?php
}

function taxonomy_client_extra_fields_save( $term_id ) {

    if ( !isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) return;

    foreach ( $_POST['term_meta'] as $slug => $value){

        switch($slug){
            default:
                $value = sanitize_title( $value );
            break;
        }

        update_term_meta( $term_id, $slug, $value );
    }

}

add_action( "job_listing_client_add_form_fields", 'taxonomy_client_extra_field_url_display' );
add_action( "job_listing_client_edit_form_fields", 'taxonomy_client_extra_field_url_display' );

add_action( 'edited_job_listing_client', 'taxonomy_client_extra_fields_save', 10, 2);
add_action( 'created_job_listing_client', 'taxonomy_client_extra_fields_save', 10, 2);
```

Comment: see also https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_edit_tag_form_fields( $tag ) {
    global $post;
    $meta_key = 'subtitle';
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $value   = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );    
?>
<tr class="form-field term-description-wrap">
    <th scope="row">
        <label for="subtitle">Subtitle</label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input name="subtitle" id="subtitle" type="text" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" size="40" />
    </td>
</tr>   
<?php
}


function custom_edited_terms( $post_id ) {   
    $meta_key = 'subtitle';
    if( isset($_POST[$meta_key]) ) {
        $meta_value = esc_attr( $_POST[$meta_key] );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, esc_attr( $_POST[meta_key], true ) );
    }
}
```